# Get amazon order report with shipping addresses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I've had a look at Amazon's _GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_ and _GET_FLAT_FILE_ACTIONABLE_ORDER_DATA_ reports but neither include any customer addresses or customer numbers, how can I get this information? (As a report if possible.)

I'm using the reports API because I can't find a strong named version of the orders API binary, if this functionality is only available in the orders API then it would be great if someone could point me towards a sn dll or the C# source code.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1):

Ah it turns out that _GET_FLAT_FILE_ORDERS_DATA_ was being cancelled by amazon and it does return the correct details. It was failing because you have to specify a start and end date.